# AnyLogic (systems dynamics) Square root function

Tags: anylogic

im simply trying to find the square root of a dynamic (changing) variable but no matter how many different ways i feed it into the equation bar i get a syntax error or "the method SQRT(double) is undefined for the type main". im having this issue with a flow.

Comment: your equation is correct, but the argument of your sqrt function is not a number... you need to look into that variable, not the equation

Comment: i still cant figure out where im going wrong. i have an inflow (of 3) to a stock (=inflow-outflow, with IV=0) that goes to a dynamic variable (=.3*stock) that then goes to an outflow (=4.91*sqrt(dynamicvariable)). when i hit build model i get no errors but when i try to run the simulation it says syntax error in outflow

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is more fundamental than your use of `sqrt`, which works fine in a simple model mimicking what you say you've done (dynamic variable taking value from a stock and then a flow taking the sqrt of that dynamic variable); see screenshot below. I think you need to provide more detail (e.g., screenshots of your model) and/or try to reproduce the problem in a simple-as-possible model.

[image: Simple model mimicking OP's model structure]

> with IV=0

What does that mean?

Comment: IV probably means initial value... so the stocks are initially equal to 0, but that's irrelevant to the problem that he has

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: see my other answer first, it is more likely your problem

> "the method SQRT(double) is undefined **for the type main**"

For some reason it is looking in "main" for a square root method. The only way I could imagine this happening is if you used `self.sqrt()` instead of  `sqrt()`

If sqrt() on its own doesn't fix it you could specify the actual location of the method

```
Math.sqrt()
```

Or to be even more explicit;

```
java.lang.Math.sqrt()
```

Answer (score 0):

> "the method **SQRT**(double) is undefined for the type main"

Method names are **case sensitive**. You should use `sqrt()` not `SQRT()`

PS: If this works, ignore my other answer